# Counting total number of points inside 2 circles

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

There are 2 circles and their centers are fixed and will be given as input. Then there will be n points, the x and y co-ordinates of which are given as input.

Finally, there will be q queries. For each query, the radius of the two circles (Let them be r1 and r2) will be given. Output the total number of points inside the first circle or the second circle for each query. A point lies inside a circle if the distance from the point to the center is less than or equal to the radius of the circle.

Constraints: n, q <= 10^6 r1,r2 <= 10^7 and for each co-ordinate, |x| and |y| <= 10^6

I'm looking for a O(nlogn) or O(nlog^2n) preprocessing and then O(logn) algorithm per query.
O(n) solution per query is too slow. Any ideas how to crack this?

Comment: Create two arrays which rank the points according to their distance. This takes O(n log(n)) for sorting. Then do a binary search per query in both arrays to find the last point in the respective circle. This takes O(log(n)).

Comment: If a point lies inside both circle then it will be counted twice

Answer (score 4):

**Solution with O(log<sup>2</sup>N) query time.**

1. It is easier for each query to count the points outside of both circles, then subtract the result from total number of points.
2. It is easier to use Cartesian coordinates. So that X would be the distance from C1, Y - the distance from C2. In this case we only need to find number of points in the area `X > r1 && Y > r2`.
3. Assign value "1" to each point. Now we only need to find sum of the values in given area. In 1D case this may be done with Fenwick tree. But 2D case is not much different if 2D Fenwick tree is used.
4. 2D Fenwick tree should occupy too much space (10<sup>12</sup> values with given constraints). But 2D array for Fenwick tree is very sparse, so we could use a hash map to store its values and decrease space requirements (and pre-processing time) to O(N log<sup>2</sup>N).

Comment: +1: This looks good.  You may be able to get away with just a 1d Fenwick tree over X if you also sort the queries by increasing Y and gradually insert the points into the Fenwick tree.

Comment: This does look good. But how can I implement a 2d Fenwick tree with such huge constraint? If the distance was always an integer then your idea would suffice. But the distance may always not be an integer. In that case if we work with the square of the distance, then the fenwick tree would need 10^12 * 10^12 space. Even though it would be sparse, I don't think this would be enough do you?

Comment: @user2040997: Each dimension of Fenwick tree updates up to log N values for each point. Which means the hash map should store up to N*log^2(N) values, for given constraints this means 400 million values. By the way, this number does not depend on constraints for x,y. If you don't need to answer queries on-line, you could use 1D Fenwick tree as suggested by Peter de Rivaz. In this case hash map is not needed. Array of size N is enough for 1D Fenwick tree (because there are only N distinct distances). [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15198176/1009831) gives some more details for 1D case.

Comment: If the memory requirements of the Fenwick tree are prohibitive, you can compromise with a kd-tree, splitting at the median of the X-direction, then the median of the Y-direction, etc. You can keep a count of the number of points under each subtree; then if a rectangle is completely in the X > r1 && Y > r1 area, we add its points to our running total; if it's completely outside that, we throw it out; and otherwise we split. This should be O(N^(1/2)) query time for 'random' queries, I think - but it might be possible to construct really bad cases where all points are on the boundary...

Answer (score 2):

Let C1, C2 be the centers of the disks. Let Pi, i = 1 ... n, be the points. Let Qj, j = 1 ... q, be the j-th query, Qj = (qj1, qj2).

1. For each point Pi, calculate d(Pi, Ck), k = 1 or 2. Put it in a sorted multimap: Mk(d(Pi, Ck)) contains Pi. This can be done in O(nlogn) (this is actually just like sorting the list of distances).
2. For each query Qj, do a binary search for qjk on the keys of Mk, which can be done in O(logn).
3. For each query Qj, take the union of the values of the multimap on the keys which are less then or equal to the one you found above.

Comment: How fast is the union step?  For large values of r1,r2 won't it be O(n)?

Comment: How can I take the union of the values of the multimap in O(logn)? I believe this can take O(n) in the worst case.

Comment: @user2040997 I believe it's(union) best scenario of merge sort.